# Vectorizing calculation of values using numpy which requires previously calculated value

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to calculate a particular formula for EMA from Investopedia which looks like

```
EmaToday = (ValueToday ∗ (Smoothing / 1+Days)) 
           + (EmaYesterday * (1 - (Smoothing / 1+Days)))
```

We can simplify this to:

```
Smoothing and Days are constants.
Let's call (Smoothing / 1 + Days) as 'M'

The simplified equation becomes:
EmaToday = ((ValueToday - EmaYesterday) * M) + EmaYesterday
```

We can do this in traditional python using loops as follows:

```
# Initialize an empty numpy array to hold calculated ema values
emaTodayArray = np.zeros((1, valueTodayArray.size - Days), dtype=np.float32)

ema = emaYesterday
# Calculate ema
for i, valueToday in enumerate(np.nditer(valueList)):
    ema = ((valueToday - ema) * M) + ema
    emaTodayArray[i] = ema
```

`emaTodayArray` holds all the computed EMA values.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to vectorize this completely as the `emaYesterday` value is needed for every new calculation.

If a full vectorization using numpy is possible first of all, I'd really appreciate it if someone can show me the way.

​

Comment: First, I don't think you need `nditer` to do that iteration; it doesn't help with speed (if that's why you used it).  And if you do use it, there is a way of getting the index as well as value, so you shouldn't have to use `enumerate`.

Comment: Your problem is essential serial in nature; one value depends on the previous.  Most of the fast compiled `numpy` operations are parallel in nature - at least from the Python perspective - all values calculated at once.  (the underlying C code is actually iterative).  The closest we get to serial operations is the `accumulate` method of `ufuncs`, with `cumsum` being the most common.

Comment: @hpaulj So essentially what you're saying is, once I fix the nditer part of the loop, there is nothing more that can be done as far as this calculation goes right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I had to fill in a few dummies to make your code run, pls check whether they are ok.

The loop can be vectorized by transforming `ema[i] ~> ema'[i] = ema[i] x (1-M)^-i` after which it becomes just a `cumsum`.

This is implemented below as `ema_pp_naive`.

The problem with this method is that for medium sized `i` (~10^3) the (1-M)^-i term may overflow rendering the result useless.

We can circumvent this problem by going to log space (using `np.logaddexp` for the summation). This `ema_pp_safe` is quite a bit more expensive than the naive method but still >10x faster than the original loop. In my quick and dirty testing this gave correct results for a million terms and beyond.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

K = 1000
Days = 0

emaYesterday = np.random.random()
valueTodayArray = np.random.random(K)
M = np.random.random()

valueList = valueTodayArray


import time

T = []

T.append(time.perf_counter())

# Initialize an empty numpy array to hold calculated ema values
emaTodayArray = np.zeros((valueTodayArray.size - Days), dtype=np.float32)

ema = emaYesterday
# Calculate ema
for i, valueToday in enumerate(np.nditer(valueList)):
    ema = ((valueToday - ema) * M) + ema
    emaTodayArray[i] = ema

T.append(time.perf_counter())

scaling = np.broadcast_to(1/(1-M), valueTodayArray.size+1).cumprod()
ema_pp_naive = ((np.concatenate([[emaYesterday], valueTodayArray * M]) * scaling).cumsum() / scaling)[1:]

T.append(time.perf_counter())

logscaling = np.log(1-M)*np.arange(valueTodayArray.size+1)
log_ema_pp = np.logaddexp.accumulate(np.log(np.concatenate([[emaYesterday], valueTodayArray * M])) - logscaling) + logscaling
ema_pp_safe = np.exp(log_ema_pp[1:])

T.append(time.perf_counter())

print(f'K = {K}')
print('naive method correct:', np.allclose(ema_pp_naive, emaTodayArray))
print('safe method correct:', np.allclose(ema_pp_safe, emaTodayArray))
print('OP {:.3f} ms   naive {:.3f} ms   safe {:.3f} ms'.format(*np.diff(T)*1000))
```

Sample runs:

```
K = 100
naive method correct: True
safe method correct: True
OP 0.236 ms   naive 0.061 ms   safe 0.053 ms

K = 1000
naive method correct: False
safe method correct: True
OP 2.397 ms   naive 0.224 ms   safe 0.183 ms

K = 1000000
naive method correct: False
safe method correct: True
OP 2145.956 ms   naive 18.342 ms   safe 108.528 ms
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Marked it correct. Took me some time to figure out how you came up with the naive version when I broke it down and worked it out. Thank you so much. I would greatly appreciate it if you could expand a little bit more about how you approached it and break down your logic at every step even for the log version. Thanks once again for taking the time to help me out! :)

Comment: @AbhishekManiyal To begin with have another look at hpaulj's comment. Accumulation of one of the builtin `ufuncs` is indeed more or less the only way of vectorizing a sequential operation (`cumsum` is essentially `add.accumulate`). Spotting that `ema` is up to scaling an accumulated sum is a matter of experience. As for the `log` version, conceptually it is really nothing more than taking the `log` of the naive version. What we gain is that (1-M)^-i which was prone to overflow is now just the very manageable -i x log (1-M). The tricky bit is that actually "one cannot take" the log of a sum ...

Comment: ... (or cumsum) in the sense that there is no closed formula for that, but luckily there is `np.logaddexp` which computes the log of a sum from the logs of the terms. It essentially does take the exp, adds and takes the log again, but in a way that is safe against overflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all help and insight!